# Get selected project name every time a project is selected

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am using ISelection to get the selected project name.

```
public static IProject getCurrentProject() {    
        IProject project = null;    
        ISelectionService selectionService = Workbench.getInstance().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService();    

        ISelection selection = selectionService.getSelection();    


        if(selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {    
            Object element = ((IStructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();    

            if (element instanceof IResource) {    
                project= ((IResource)element).getProject();    

            }  
            else if (element instanceof IJavaElement) {    
                IJavaProject jProject= ((IJavaElement)element).getJavaProject();    
                project = jProject.getProject();    
            }



        }

        return project;  
    }
```

The problem is that this function returns the project name only on the first time execution.

When I call it on a button event, I get a null pointer exception and it seems that element is null.

What I have to change to get the selected project name everytime I call this function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Workbench` is an **internal** class and you must not use it [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html). Use:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
```

to get the `IWorkbench` instance.

`ISelectionService.getSelection` returns the selection in the currently active part so if you call this from an editor or view you get the selection in that not the selection in Package/Project explorer.

You can call `ISelectionService.getSelection("part id")` to get the selection in a particular part - but you have to work out the part id.

You can use `ISelectionService.addPostSelectionListener` to be told about changes in the selection of all parts.

Comment: I'm developing a plugin that's why I used Workbench , I try to get the selected project name where the plugin runs, my function returns the selected project name but just on the first time execution (when the view in the plugin is loaded)....I need to solve this....

Comment: Workbench is not acceptable anywhere outside of the core Eclipse code. It is an internal class and can be changed without notice.

Comment: Probably the first time you run your code the Package Explorer is the active part and you get the selection. On the other runs something else is the active part and it has an empty selection. Each part has its own separate selection.